# 1 of the all object methods not working with eventHandler mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, event-listener

**All methods in the class above are working fine if a call them.**

**But when I call them with addEventListener(Click), the object method open() does not work but other methods work here also.**
**Kindly help me find where have I made the error?**

```
class Cell {
    constructor (x,y) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.w = cellWidth
        this.h = cellHeight
        this.opened = false
        this.hasMine = true

    }
    squareTest () {
        c.beginPath()
        c.rect(100,100,100,100)
        c.stroke()
    }

    cellBody () {
        c.beginPath()
        c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 100, 100, 0.1)"
        c.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 100, 100, 1)"
        c.rect (this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h)
        c.fill()
        c.stroke ()

        if (this.opened === true) {
            if (this.hasMine === true) {
             c.beginPath();
             c.ellipse(this.x + this.w/2, this.y + this.w/2, 10, 10, 15,0,Math.PI*2,false);
             c.stroke()
            }
        }
    }

    open () {
        if(this.opened == false) {this.opened = true}
    }
        }

}
```

// I have removed some code here to make this post short.

// open() function works fine without addEventListener(Click), 
// But other methods work well anywhere, so what is different with open() ?

// table [0][0] is the object of the Class Cell

```
table[0][0].open();
// works fine here

table[0][0].squareTest();
// works fine here

canvas.addEventListener ('click', function (event) 
  {
    table[0][0].open(); // DOES NOT WORK HERE

    table[0][0].squareTest(); //works fine here
    console.log (table[1][1]); //works fine
    }
)

table[0][0].open();
    // works fine here
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Likely a binding issue since JS binds `this` late.

Comment: Where is this click being called from in the code?

Comment: @DaveNewton open() function has been given a task to do something, when I type table[0][0].open() without eventlistener Click it performs the task. With eventlistener Click, table[0][0].squareTest performs it task but table[0][0].squareTest does not perform its function.

If I am still not able to explain the issue, I can share my complete sheet. It conatains less than 200 lines

Comment: @epascarello In the real sheet the click was on a specific area. But to find my error, I simplified my code with a click anywhere on the canvas. In this simplified code also all other table[0][0]functions are performed are working except table[0][0].open(), and the strange thing is that table[0][0] also works well without eventlistener. 

I can share my sheet if required (under 200 lines)

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Is there an error in the console? Related to `this` being undefined?

Comment: The issue is resolved now. I did not missed to link a further with open() function, which was not performing the task upon clicking.
BTW there was no error in the console..... Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

canvas.addEventListener add an anonymous function to be called onclick

You should assign a variable to table[0][0] outside if you want to call it inside that function.

```
const tb = table[0][0];
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) 
   {
     tb.open();
     tb.squareTest();
   }
);
```

This way you will have a reference to that table to be used inside your onclick function;

This is assuming you have a console error that says table[0][0] is undefined. Is this the case?

Comment: This does not seems to be the case. As I have declared the Table array independently as var table and pushed elements with for loop.
Also, if I write the eventListener "console.log(table[0][0]" It logs the correct value on the console.

To me it seems table[0][0] is accessible...

Answer (score 0):

There was no error in the code....
But I was not getting the desired output because there was another function which was not called with the open()

Thanks everyone :)